# Twitch embedded player in UIWebView: Play Button disappears (iOS, HTML5)

Tags: xcode, iframe, stream, embed, twitch

Heyhey,

I have a problem with the HTML5 embedded player while trying to use it in an UIWebView in an iOS project.

```
UIWebView *twitchStream = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, newW, newH)];
NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><iframe height='%f' width='%f' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='http://www.twitch.tv/rocketbeanstv/embed'></iframe></body></html>", twitchStream.frame.size.height, twitchStream.frame.size.width];
[twitchStream loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
[_scrollView addSubview:twitchStream];
```

I load the iframe code from above into the UIWebView and the video is loading correctly at first and I can start and watch if I'm fast enough to click the PLAY button. But after some seconds the video seems to disappear and the UIWebView just shows (what I guess) the thumbnail/preview image, so I cannot start it from there.

Summary: Everything seems to work if I'm fast enough to touch the PLAY button before the content of the iframe changes and only displays an image of the stream.

And btw: the same happens if I put the HTML code onto my website and try to check it in iOS' Safari (demonstration (first working because fast clicking the play button, then reloading page and waiting + play button disappearing): https://vid.me/Cnbc)

Any ideas?

Edit: Same problem with their official iOS Viewing Plugin (http://dev.twitch.tv)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( But also didn't try again after a while. So I don't know if that already is fixed...